# Почему неверно срабатывает условие?

Tags: python

Мужики, я рискую словить много минусов, чую. Но глаза уже капитально замылились, а что не так - не пойму. Есть валидация протокола:

```
def is_url_with_correct_protocol(url):
    # Correct mean is https or http
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
    scheme = urlparse(url).scheme
    if scheme != "http" or scheme != "https":
        return False
    return True
```

Есть тест:

```
def test_is_url_with_correct_protocol(self):
    self.assertFalse(helpers.is_url_with_correct_protocol('vk.com/abc'))
    self.assertFalse(helpers.is_url_with_correct_protocol('ftp://vk.com/abc'))
    self.assertTrue(helpers.is_url_with_correct_protocol('http://vk.com/abc'))
    self.assertTrue(helpers.is_url_with_correct_protocol('https://vk.com/abc'))
```

Который благополучно валится. Функция ведет себя не пойми как, что я только не делал.

```
    self.assertTrue(helpers.is_url_with_correct_protocol('http://vk.com/abc'))
AssertionError: False is not true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if scheme != "http"` **and** `scheme != "https":`

P.S.

Вам стоило бы обдумать тему отмечания ответов на Ваши вопросы как принятых.

Comment: Спасибо! Стыдно..) Отмечу через 9 минут, тайм аут сайта не позволяет

Comment: На здоровье. Успехов!